# What's the joke behind "Fiscally responsible mime"?

Tags: hearthstone

There are many joke options in Hearthstone's [Finding Opponent spinner](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Finding_Opponent).  Most of them are clearly references or jokes.  But I don't know what to make of the "Fiscally responsible mime".

Is it a reference to something I don't recognize?  Is it a pun (like "A cardish Ian")?  Is it an in-joke for Blizzard employees?  Is it just there to make people boggle?

Comment: Are there synonyms for "fiscally responsible" that might make this joke make sense?

Comment: I always thought that was all it ment, there may not be an answer.

Comment: @peper757 - It's certainly possible. But it seems very random to not have *some* meaning behind it.

Comment: When is the last time *you've* encountered a *fiscally responsible* mime? Yeah? I thought so!

Comment: I once saw a mime try to withdraw invisible money from an invisible ATM but his account was empty. The recession hit everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is just a gag that *tries* to be funny using a paradox. I wouldn't search for a true reference behind it. In the Italian version there are a lot of entries like this, as (translating) "Animal-right activist hunter", or "unarmed warrior" (not sure if these voices also exist in the English version, but I think that each country has they own ones).

Comment: Interesting.  I can definitely see that as being the intended joke, except that I don't quite get why "fiscally responsible" would be opposite of "mime".

Comment: @Bobson: Maybe they intend "mime" more as a virtual "substitute", "doppelganger", "look-alike". If your mime, in this acceptation, makes a legal "mess" in your shoes, you remain the responsible one for the society (even because your mime is not intended to be "physical"). At least, that's my interpretation. Again, I don't think this can make you LOL, anyway. :-)

Comment: A mime who isn't frivolous with their spending is a *paradox*?  If I were a mime, I'd be pretty insulted right now!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's supposed to be funny due to its irrelevance?

If I had to choose one adjective to describe a mime, it probably wouldn't be *"fiscally responsible,"* even if that were true.  Nobody asks *(or cares)* how fiscally responsible a mime is, so using that adjective seems completely random.

And random is funny.   Kind of.

Comment: A non sequitur?